# TCL substitution

Tags: shell, tcl

I have to run a script where I have to give some password as the argument. The password contains special characters.

Say I am calling a script with `test.tcl system$123`.

On trying to access the arg with

```
set name [lindex $argv 0]
```

These special characters are ignored.

Please help me on this.

Thanks,
Ramya.

Comment: Make sure your shell isn't interpolating ``$123`` into a blank string.  ``puts $argv`` to see what you're actually dealing with. If the issue isn't there, please post a little more of your code, particularly your starting lines.

Answer (score 8):

Tcl doesn't ignore the special characters. There's basically nothing that a tcl string can't contain.

The shell however may interpret the special character differently. Try calling it this way:

```
test.tcl 'system$123'
```

Remember that most shells, like tcl, implements `$` substitution.

Comment: An alternative is `test.tcl system\$123` but that's just a different way to guard against system shell quoting.